# Trigger dependent jobs in teamcity

Tags: triggers, teamcity

I have Project A,B and C. I want to configure Teamcity in such a way that, when I run Project B build , it should first run Project A , Project B and at the end Project C. How should I configure?

Order::
I will run Project B, but it should wait until Project A is built.
Then, 
Project B will run.
Finally, Project C will be kicked off. How can I achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give project B a snapshot dependency on project A.
Give project C a finished build trigger on project B.

When you manually run B it will first queue A due to the dependency. If A and B both succeed, the trigger will then queue C.